# Send email automatically using outlook from excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, excel-2007

I am trying to send an open workbook (Excel) every day at 5pm. Here is my code:

I put this one in a module

```
Sub SendEmail()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = "yourmail"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Report"
        .Body = "Hello!"
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName

        .Send
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:00:00"), "SendEmail"

End Sub
```

and i put this one in ThisWorkbook

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:00:00"), "SendEmail"
End Sub
```

My workbook is open all the time.
I can't get the email, except I hit the run button in Excel. I want it do automatically everyday.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is add a new sub that sets up the time schedule that is called from the open command and the email, which will cause it to reset daily.

Add this Sub:

```
Sub SetSchedule()

Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:00:00"), "SendEmail"

Application.OnTime TimeValue("23:59:00"), "SetSchedule"

End Sub
```

And call it from the open sub:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

    Call SetSchedule

End Sub
```

You can then delete the `Application.OnTime` call from the email sub itself

Answer (score 0):

Your best option will be a simple Recurring task Item set it by using a reminder to recur everyday at 17:00

Example:
Create your custom Task Item to recur at 1700

Add the following code to ThisOutlookSession

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal item As Object)
'   Now call your VBA Code

End Sub
```

As soon as reminder fires, your email will be sent automatically.